# C# Rounding issue

Tags: c#

I have a double called int_step which i'm increasing every loop and expect to end when I have reached 1. However it iterates too much as rounding throws in some unexpected behaviour.

For some reason the following code adds quite nicely, but close to 1 i get an offset:

```
            int_step += 0.01;

            // TODO : Fix rounding step in double with step increase of + 0.01, provides error because value will become 1.000000007
            if (int_step >= 1)
                int_step = 1;
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and what the correct way is to solve this?

Comment: not sure I understand what you're saying is happening but it sounds like Mid Point Rounding Away From Zero issue

Comment: Why aren't you using an int from 1 to 100? doubles and floats have rounding issues, and if you need precision you should use another type, like decimal.